# Convert from python HTTP request to C# HTTP request

Tags: c#, python

I have the following http post request in python:

```
auth_req = requests.post(baseurl,
                         data={'username': 'User', 'password': 'Password', 'output_mode': 'json'}, verify=False)
```

I'm trying to "Convert" the request to C# as follow:

```
var tHttpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            // adds basic headers

tHttpReq.ContentType = "application/json";
tHttpReq.Method = "POST";
tHttpReq.Accept = "application/json";
using (StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(tHttpReq.GetRequestStream()))
{
      // creates request body in the concrete class
      string rBody = "{\"username\": \"User\", \"password\": \"Password\", \"output_mode\": \"json\"}";
       // writes the data to the stream
       sWriter.Write(rBody);
       sWriter.Flush();
}
var webHttpResp = (HttpWebResponse)tHttpReq.GetResponse();
```

And i got Bad request error, What is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: where is the webRequest coming from ? You should use the tHttpReq instead of I reckon

Comment: @Newboy, yeah its a typo, edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

Using HttpClient makes it easier. You can do something like this:

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://yourEndPoint.com");
        HttpContent content = new StringContent("{'json' : 'value'}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var result = await client.PostAsync("/endpoint", content);
        var contentAsString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```